# Express redirects to wrong view after passport authentication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm having quite the time figuring out why the URL is updating but it goes to the wrong view.

When a user is authenticated with passport, the URL updates to my code (/clients) but the view goes back to the homepage view.

After the user is authenticated, i'd like them to be redirected to my angular app.

```
folder structure

  server
     --config
          -auth
          -express
          -mongoose
          -passport
          -routes
     --controllers
     --data
     --utils
     --views
         -client (ng app)
             -css
             -js
             -views
             index.jade (angular app index)
         -shared
              layout.jade
         -users
              login.jade
         index.jade (express index)
```

express.js

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.set('views', config.rootPath + '/server/views/');
```

auth.js

```
login: function(req, res, next) {
    var auth = passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (!user) {
            req.session.error = 'Invalid Username or Password!';
            res.redirect('/login');
        }

        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            res.redirect('/client');
            console.log();
        })
    });
        auth(req, res, next);
    },...
```

Routes.js

```
var auth = require('./auth'),
    controllers = require('../controllers');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/register', controllers.users.getRegister);
    app.post('/register', controllers.users.createUser);

    app.post('/login', auth.login);
    app.get('/logout', auth.logout);
    app.get('/login', controllers.users.getLogin);

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.render('index', {currentUser: req.user});
    });

    app.get('*', function (req, res) {
        res.render('index', {currentUser: req.user});
    });
};
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction, i'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with passport.js; you aren't handling the `/client` route so it is caught by `'*'` and express renders `'index'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a route

```
   app.get('/client', function (req, res) {
     res.render('client/index', {currentUser: req.session.user});
   });
```